# Windows 8.1 RT apps won't work

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-store-app

Windows apps open (?), I can see the icon on the taskbar but when I click on it, the desktop seems to give its place to the app, but the app minimizes instantly (in fractions of a second) and I can't use it, like if it's constantly minimized. The apps used to work fine and sometimes they do now. I have nothing suspicious installed on my system. Any idea why the apps window won't maximize?

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled?  This is required to launch `Modern UI` applications from the Windows Store.  There is a `Microsoft Fixit` tool that can fix issues that cause this symptom have you used it?

Comment: Yes, I log in with a username and password and they used to work. They still do sometimes, but now I can't open any of them. They're all minimized until I close them with right click->close

Comment: @Ramhound: How can I search for the fix-it you mentioned? Do you have a link?

Comment: its located  [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab) and some [Additional Information](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20291-windows-store-apps-troubleshooter-fix-apps-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: @Ramhound: thank you for the link. Unfortunately it won't resolve all the matters it detected. It couldn't fix "service registration missing or corrupt", "windows store cache may be damaged" and "windows store configuration may be damaged". It fixed "some security settings are missing or have been changed"

Comment: Your installation is corrupt.  Use DISM to repair the component store, then SFC to repair the corrupt files, or use `Refresh` but that will require you to install your x86 applications again.

Comment: @Ramhound: sfc didn't find any corrupt files! I don't know how to use DISM so I searched the internet and found this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx . I hope it helps! Thanks for your input!

Comment: check all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981: I've checked the link and I found some useful information about reporting. Ramhound's idea about DISM worked though! DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth.

Comment: @Ramhound: you can post the DISM solution if you'd like the credit!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually given by Ramhound but he/she didn't post it. What made the apps work again was the command:`DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth` .